# Volume Slider using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I'm new to coding, and I am attempting to create a juke box for a school project, but I'm struggling to create a slider that will edit the volume. I'm just unsure where to start to get the volume to actually change as I move the slider.
I'm using VLC lib.

```
import vlc
import random
from tkinter import *
import threading



song = ""
instance = vlc.Instance()

def get_songs():
    global song
    global x
    global songs
    songs = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    x = 0
    song = songs[x]
    print(songs)
    commence(song)

def pause_resume():
    player.pause()

def commence(song):
    global player
    global x
    player = instance.media_player_new()
    media = instance.media_new(song)
    player.set_media(media)
    player.play()


def next_song():
    if x >= len(songs):
        print("Error: Can't go any further")
        x = 0
        return
    player.stop()
    song = songs[x]
    commence(song)







window = Tk()

window.geometry("600x600")
window.title('JukeBox')

#pause_button = Button(window, text = "Next", command = next_song)
#pause_button.grid(row=1, column = 2)
Button(window, text="Start", command=get_songs).grid(column=1,row=1)
Button(window, text="Next", command=next_song).grid(column=1,row=2)
pause_button = Button(window, text = "Pause/Resume", command = pause_resume)
pause_button.grid(row=3, column = 1)
menubar = Menu(window)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=get_songs())
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=window.destroy)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
window.config(menu=menubar)
vol = Scale(window,from_ = 0,to = 1,orient = HORIZONTAL ,resolution = .1,)
vol.grid(row = 1, column = 2)




window.mainloop()
```

I understand I'm not using the best coding practices, but this way I can actually understand what I have written.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe [this](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_sliders.php) might help.

Comment: Yea that helped me understand the slider a bit more, but im more worried about how to change the volume as it slides?

Comment: Maybe `command` option is what you need? Here's a simple example (you are getting the value of scale while moving the slider): http://pastebin.com/S292a2VL

Answer (score 0):

Set the `command` parameter when creating the `Scale` widget:

```
def set_volume(v):
    global vol
    global player
    # either get the new volume from given argument v (type: str):
    # value = int(v)
    # or get it directly from Scale widget (type: int)
    value = vol.get()
    player.audio_set_volume(value)

vol = Scale(..., command=set_volume)
```

Comment: I've tried this, It says I have one argument and it requires zero. I've semi solved my problem using a button to update the volume

def show_value():
    i = vol.get()
    player.audio_set_volume(i)

vol = Scale(window,from_ = 0,to = 100,orient = HORIZONTAL ,resolution = 1) 
vol.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
vol_but = Button(window, text='Update Volume', command=show_value)
vol_but.grid(row =2, column = 2)

Answer (score 0):

My mate was able to help me with this by simply adding self in the required paramaters of the function, no clue why it helps and thanks everyone for trying, much appreciated.

```
def show_value(self):
    global player
    i = vol.get()
    player.audio_set_volume(i)

vol = Scale(window,from_ = 0,to = 100,orient = HORIZONTAL ,resolution = 1,command = show_value) 
    vol.place(x=75, y = 300)
    vol.set(50)
```